# Android Jetpack DataStore item separation

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to migrate to Jetpack `DataStore` from good ol' `SharedPreferences` and there is one thing I am struggling to come to terms with and that is the amount/size of the data pulling out of `DataStore` at once.

`SharedPreferences` were asynchronous and it was usually used in a way that they had one accessor with over exhaustive list of getters and setters - not supersophisticated but worked fine. **There wasn't an issue with fetching multiple settings that were not necessarily related to each other.**

`DataStore` is synchronous only, with `suspend fun`ctions and `Flow`s(which comes with its own set of headaches). `DataStore` offers options to pull out a single preference with the `Flow` or `Flow` of a user-defined set of preferences grouped in a `data class`.

**Here is my problem.** I am not sure how to approach getting multiple preferences at once. This is something I can do with `Flow`s `combine` and it works fine but this also has a limit on how many of you can get at once and it doesn't look great.

```
combine(
    preferences.preferenceA,
    preferences.preferenceB,
    preferences.preferenceC,
    preferences.preferenceD,
    preferences.preferenceE
)
```

I can still make it this amount of flows with previously mentioned data classes so the amount of data I can have at one asynchronous place is enough but in principle, this feels like I would be forced to couple data just for the sake of coupling.

OR

Just have one big preference object/data class with all of the preferences in it - basically how `SharedPreferences` were used before but this would make each "client" that would ever need something from it would hold all of it.

Either of the solutions "sounds" like a wrong one.